# WordPress Featured Post Slider

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Alright, I have almost finished up a clients project in WordPress, but I have hit a wall. I am not really great with jQuery (and I have yet to find a plugin to achieve what they are looking for). The client wants an automatic slider on the homepage that pulls in featured posts out of their five categories. I have scoured the net for plugins to achieve the "look" they want, but to no avail.

The look in question can be seen [here](http://cl.ly/6Crd).

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things you probably have to do yourself, even though there are some slider plugins,  they are difficult to customize.

Using a jquery slider is pretty straightforward, they are usually just controlled with ID's and CLASS's, so you can wrap any WordPress code, for instance a wp_query (for featured posts).

toscho's answer pretty much covers it, I tend to use Jquery Tools a lot since it has great docs and tons of functionality, http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [AnythingSlider for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anythingslider-for-wordpress/) plugin. Should do everything you need it to do.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the Slides.js and wrapping my different queries with the divs. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Anything Slider](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) to do this. A checkbox added to the post editor …

[image]

… and a simple query later …

```
// excerpt from my slider class
public function list_slider_items()
{
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'featuredpost'
        ,   'meta_value' => 'on'
        )
    );

    if ( empty ( $posts ) or ! is_array( $posts ) )
    {
        print '<!-- no posts found -->';
        return;
    }

    $out = '<ul id=slider class=noprint>';

    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        $out .= '<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'slider-img' )
            . '<span class="slider-cat-list">'
            . get_the_category_list( ' · ', 'single', $post->ID )
            . '</span>'
            . '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">'
            . get_the_title( $post->ID )
            . ' <span class=more-link>Weiterlesen</span></a></h2></li>';
    }

    print $out . '</ul>';
}
```

… and it is nearly done.

You have to tweak the stylesheet very much. It’s a mess. But in the end you get a slider that can contain any HTML, is usable for keyboard users and fits to a percentage width.

Comment: Thanks toscho. I will definitely give it a go.  Just curious, how did you add the check box?

Comment: @Louis Stephens The class for meta boxes is part of my private theme framework. Strange, right now I cannot find a good tutorial for that … but there are plugins to create such a box from the backend, for example [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/). You may take a look into the source code of these plugins.

Comment: Yeah, I am still struggling with the slider (actually have not even started on it). You can see a screenshot of what they want below http://cl.ly/6Ry7