# WordPress Page Id

Tags: url-rewriting, pages

I have a client (same for my [previous post about the slider](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15512/wordpress-featured-post-slider)) who believes that the url structure needs to include a "google page id" to be compliant with google news. Therefore, they want the url structure set up like: http://www.sitename.com/blog/article-name-goes-here?p=85532  . I think they want just a unique 3+ number id associated with every post. Does anyone know how to go about this?

I am quite good with design and front-end dev, but when it comes to WordPress loops or settings sometimes I am just clueless.

Comment: Have you got a link to where I can read up about this "Google page ID"? I've not heard about this before and just intrigued what your client means by this.

Comment: @Brady - have a look here: http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68323 - basically there's a requirement for a URL to have a unique (to that site) 3 digit (at least) identifier in the URL

Comment: Thanks for the link. Learnt something more today. Although I'd rather go down the route of creating a news sitemap rather than sticking to the Google page id.

Comment: In regards to what @Brady said, you can use a news sitemap to avoid having to use the unique numeric ID. More information: https://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?answer=74288

Comment: Is the client already approved for Google news and being indexed as news?  [Yoast WordPres SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) also contains news site map capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Permalink page (in Settings), and choose custom structure, and use something like this:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/00%post_id%
```

Comment: Thanks @anu .. Do you know if there is anyway for the post id to be "3+"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh sorry. Just in the article (http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68323) it says that the page must have an unique id with 3 or more numbers

Comment: @Louis Stephens - just add an extra 0 to be sure all your posts will have larger than 3 digit ids - this deals with the few posts with single digit ids (ie the very earliest ones).

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying doing something like http://sitename.com/%post_id%00 for the custom url structure?

Comment: No - I've updated my answer. This will give you a url that looks like sitename.com/title-of-a-blog-post/00234 (where 234 is the post-id).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a unique numeric identifier by using a [News Sitemap](https://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?answer=74288).

From Google's News [technical requirements](https://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68323):

> The URL
>   for each article must contain a unique
>   number consisting of at least three
>   digits. For example, we can't crawl an
>   article with this URL:
>   http://www.google.com/news/article23.html.
>   We can, however, crawl an article with
>   this URL:
>   http://www.google.com/news/article234.html.
>   Keep in mind that if the only number
>   in the article consists of an isolated
>   four-digit number that starts with 199
>   or 200, we won't be able to crawl it.
>   **Please note that this rule is waived
>   with News sitemaps.**

The [XML Sitemap & Google News Sitemap Feeds](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xml-sitemap-feed/) plugin for WordPress should be able to take care of this automatically for you.